# Checking how many inputs per month between two dates

Tags: r

I need to check how many times a participant interacted with an app between two visits.

The data frame consists of the patients ID (56 participants in total). The registration date which is the date they interacted with the app and visit dates 1 and 2. Each patient has different visit dates and interacts with the app differently.

```
PatientId      registrationDate   Visit1Date  Visit2Date 
XXX/01         2019-12-04         2019-12-01  2020-04-01
XXX/01         2019-12-14         2019-12-01  2020-04-01
XXX/01         2020-01-01         2019-12-01  2020-04-01
XXX/01         2020-02-12         2019-12-01  2020-04-01
XXX/01         2020-03-16         2019-12-01  2020-04-01
XXX/01         2020-03-26         2019-12-01  2020-04-01
XXX/01         2020-04-18         2019-12-01  2020-04-01
XXX/02         2020-01-04         2019-12-04  2020-04-16
```

What is the best way to check how many times they interacted with the app on a monthly basis between visit 1 and 2?

I expect the output would look like this. With Month1 being if the participant interacted with the app (i.e. registration date) between Visit1Date and Visit1Date+1 month. Month 2 being if the participant interacted with the app (i.e. registration date) between Visit1Date+1 month and Visit1Date+2 month.

```
PatientId      registrationDate   Visit1Date  Visit2Date  Month1  Month2
XXX/01         2019-12-04         2019-12-01  2020-04-01  Yes     N/A
XXX/01         2019-12-14         2019-12-01  2020-04-01  Yes     N/A
XXX/01         2020-01-01         2019-12-01  2020-04-01  N/A     Yes
XXX/01         2020-02-12         2019-12-01  2020-04-01  N/A     N/A
XXX/01         2020-03-16         2019-12-01  2020-04-01  N/A     N/A
XXX/01         2020-03-26         2019-12-01  2020-04-01  N/A     N/A
XXX/01         2020-04-18         2019-12-01  2020-04-01  N/A     N/A
XXX/02         2020-01-04         2019-12-04  2020-04-16  Yes     N/A
```

Then I could aggregate for each participant to sum the number of times they interacted in each month between their visits

```
PatientId   Month1  Month2
XXX/01      2       1
XXX/02      1       N/A
```

Comment: Convert your columns to dates (if necesssary).  Then use `%within%` from the [lubridate package](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/within-interval.html) to create a presence/absence flag for each row and then sum the flag within each patient..

Comment: This seems like the best command to use. The problem is I also need to split the two visit dates into months between. I don't want to check between just visit 1 and 2 but each month between visit 1 and 2.

Comment: Please calculate the expected output by hand and show it in the queestion.

Comment: probably `data.table::foverlaps()` can help you. Impossible to provide a solid answer based on this sample data (and a missing dsired output). Please provide both.

Comment: Again using lubridate, eg `seq(ymd('2019-12-01'),ymd('2020-04-01'), by = '1 month')` will give you your sequence of months for each observation. `tidyr::expand()` can give you one row for each month between `Visit1Date1 and `Visit2Date`.  As others have said, you're not helping us to help you by providing your input data in an unhelpful format.

Comment: Should the output on row 3 not be month1 = NA, month2 = yes ?

Comment: I have updated my question. I'm sorry for missing things, I am not trying to be purposely unhelpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could work..

One problem when working woth month ans not days/weeks/years is to tackle the question/definition of "what is a month?"
Is a month equal to 4 weeks, 30 days, from 1-jan-2020 until 1-feb-2020, or 365.25/12 days, or..., or... ?

In the solution below, I calculated with calendar months, to a month is based on the calendat-month.
4-feb to 3-mar = 1 month
14 jan to 13 feb = 1 month,
etc.

```
library( data.table )
library( lubridate )

#create sample data
DT <- fread("PatientId      registrationDate   Visit1Date  Visit2Date 
XXX/01         2019-12-04         2019-12-01  2020-04-01
XXX/01         2019-12-14         2019-12-01  2020-04-01
XXX/01         2020-01-01         2019-12-01  2020-04-01
XXX/01         2020-02-12         2019-12-01  2020-04-01
XXX/01         2020-03-16         2019-12-01  2020-04-01
XXX/01         2020-03-26         2019-12-01  2020-04-01
XXX/01         2020-04-18         2019-12-01  2020-04-01
XXX/02         2020-01-04         2019-12-04  2020-04-16")
col.date <- names(DT)[-1]
DT[, (col.date) := lapply( .SD, as.Date, format = "%Y-%m-%d" ), .SDcols = col.date ]

#code
#calculate monthly difference
DT[ between( registrationDate, Visit1Date, Visit2Date), 
    m.diff := paste0( "month", interval( Visit1Date, registrationDate ) %/% months(1) + 1 ) ]
#summarise and cast
ans <- DT[ , .N, by = .(PatientId, m.diff) ]
dcast( ans[ m.diff %in% c("month1", "month2"), ], PatientId ~ m.diff, value.var = "N", fill = 0 )

#    PatientId month1 month2
# 1:    XXX/01      2      1
# 2:    XXX/02      0      1
```

Comment: Yes I agree month is ambiguous and I would choose to define this differently next time! However I have found your code extremely helpful and it seems to have successfully implemented what I wanted to do. I thank you for being patient and providing an answer, it is very much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly, perhaps you want to check for how many consecutive months a patient interacted with the app. I have used two libraries/packages for solving this.  `lubridate` and `tidyverse` (you may load only `dplyr` and `tidyr` if you want so).  Strategy used-

- used `lubridate::floor_date()` to extract month-year only.
- used `tidyr::complete()` to fill missing months, if any.  Added months/dates will have `NA` in other data which will be used next
- used `dplyr::dense_rank()` to have a sequential count of each interaction
- count `NA`s to sum number of interactions
- lastly used `tidyr::pivot_wider()` to restructure output like yours

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>% group_by(PatientId) %>%
  mutate(mons = floor_date(registrationDate, unit = "month")) %>%
  complete(mons = seq.Date(min(floor_date(Visit1Date, "month")), max(floor_date(Visit2Date, "month")), by = "month")) %>%
  mutate(mons = paste0("Month", dense_rank(mons))) %>%
  group_by(PatientId, mons) %>%
  summarise(d = sum(!is.na(registrationDate))) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = PatientId, names_from = mons, values_from = d)

# A tibble: 2 x 6
# Groups:   PatientId [2]
  PatientId Month1 Month2 Month3 Month4 Month5
  <chr>      <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>
1 XXX/01         2      1      1      2      1
2 XXX/02         0      1      0      0      0
```

dput used

```
df <- structure(list(PatientId = c("XXX/01", "XXX/01", "XXX/01", "XXX/01", 
"XXX/01", "XXX/01", "XXX/01", "XXX/02"), registrationDate = structure(c(18234, 
18244, 18262, 18304, 18337, 18347, 18370, 18265), class = "Date"), 
    Visit1Date = structure(c(18231, 18231, 18231, 18231, 18231, 
    18231, 18231, 18234), class = "Date"), Visit2Date = structure(c(18353, 
    18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18368), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = "data.frame")

> df
  PatientId registrationDate Visit1Date Visit2Date
1    XXX/01       2019-12-04 2019-12-01 2020-04-01
2    XXX/01       2019-12-14 2019-12-01 2020-04-01
3    XXX/01       2020-01-01 2019-12-01 2020-04-01
4    XXX/01       2020-02-12 2019-12-01 2020-04-01
5    XXX/01       2020-03-16 2019-12-01 2020-04-01
6    XXX/01       2020-03-26 2019-12-01 2020-04-01
7    XXX/01       2020-04-18 2019-12-01 2020-04-01
8    XXX/02       2020-01-04 2019-12-04 2020-04-16
```

If you want NAs instead of `0` use this

```
df %>% group_by(PatientId) %>%
  mutate(mons = floor_date(registrationDate, unit = "month")) %>%
  complete(mons = seq.Date(min(floor_date(Visit1Date, "month")), max(floor_date(Visit2Date, "month")), by = "month")) %>%
  mutate(mons = paste0("Month", dense_rank(mons))) %>%
  group_by(PatientId, mons) %>%
  summarise(d = sum(!is.na(registrationDate))) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = PatientId, names_from = mons, values_from = d) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ifelse(. == 0, NA, .)))

# A tibble: 2 x 6
# Groups:   PatientId [2]
  PatientId Month1 Month2 Month3 Month4 Month5
  <chr>      <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>
1 XXX/01         2      1      1      2      1
2 XXX/02        NA      1     NA     NA     NA
```

If you want output for first two months of interaction only as shown in the example, use this

```
df %>% group_by(PatientId) %>%
  mutate(mons = floor_date(registrationDate, unit = "month")) %>%
  complete(mons = seq.Date(min(floor_date(Visit1Date, "month")), max(floor_date(Visit2Date, "month")), by = "month")) %>%
  filter(dense_rank(mons) <= 2) %>%
  mutate(mons = paste0("Month", dense_rank(mons))) %>%
  group_by(PatientId, mons) %>%
  summarise(d = sum(!is.na(registrationDate))) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = PatientId, names_from = mons, values_from = d) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ifelse(. == 0, NA, .)))

# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   PatientId [2]
  PatientId Month1 Month2
  <chr>      <int>  <int>
1 XXX/01         2      1
2 XXX/02        NA      1
```